# Digital Key Signature without retrieving the private key - Luna HSM

Tags: digital-signature, private-key, hsm

I currently try to do a ECDSA Signature with a Luna HSM. This did work so far.

```
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Luna");
        ks.load(null, null);
        Key key = ks.getKey("keyAlias", null);
        String message = "Sign this!";
        byte messageBytes[] = message.getBytes();
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA","LunaProvider");
        sig.initSign((PrivateKey) key);
        sig.update(messageBytes);
```

But now I'm wondering if it is possible to do a key signature, without retrieving the private key out of the HSM? My understanding is, that retrieving the private key out of the HSM contradicts the whole idea of an HSM.

It would be great, if somebody could help me with this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you double checked? Is it returning key or just handle to private key? And then signing operation happens inside HSM using private key handle ?! Thus private key may not come out of HSM.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.
Im not totally sure, if only the handle is returned.
I did print out the key and got the following output.

Private Key:
LunaKey: handle=69, class=3, type=3
[B@48e1f6c7

From the output it indeed looks like only the handle is returned.

But the API description rather sounds like the whole key is returned.

(getKey)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getKey(java.lang.String,%20char[])

Comment: Yes, from the response you can see there are not private key bytes.  Only Handle. Thus consumer application is passing key handle to HSM and Signature is being returned by HSM. Thus you can accept my answer ! ;)